# Vim freezes in insert mode when .vimrc contains set tags=tags;

Tags: vim, freeze, ctags

I am using vim-gtk on Ubuntu 16.04 and use exuberant-ctags to generate a tags file in the root directory of my project. My instance of vim would randomly freeze in insert mode, usually after inserting a full stop (.) and the only thing I could do is close that terminal and open a new instance of vim in a new terminal. I was able to narrow the problem down to something with ctags by removing things from my .vimrc file. When I remove `set tags=tags;`, vim works fine and never freezes. I have also noticed that if I remove the tags file in my root directory, it no longer freezes even though `set tags=tags;` is in the vimrc.

Things I have tried:

- other questions mentioned Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Q. When it freezes in insert mode Ctrl+Q has no effect and I am sure I am not accidentally typing Ctrl+S since I have tried pressing it intentionally and then Ctrl+Q does work.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling vim, vim-gnome, vim-gtk, etc...
- Uninstalling and reinstalling exuberant-ctags

Neither of these fix the problem.
Has anyone encountered this problem before?
If there is no obvious fix, can anyone recommend an alternative to exuberant-ctags that can be used with vim without making it freeze on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Vim was freezing because my tags file was too large. I added several directories and filetypes to .agignore and then reran ctags using `ctags -R --exclude=@.agignore` which resulted in a much smaller tags file (19MB instead of 2GB) and now vim no longer freezes